# Want random picture screensaver, then sleep

Tags: mac, sleep, screensaver

When I configure my mac (leopard) to use the "random picture" screensaver after 10 minutes, and to go to sleep after 1 hour of inactivity, it won't ever go to sleep.  It seems that it refuses to go to sleep if there is disk activity, and the picture screensaver accesses the disk.  But this seems like a really stupid design.

Is there a way around this?  A smarter screensaver or sleep program?  Putting the pictures in a ramdisk of some sort?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out Apple created a market for fixes to this problem, so there is [Safe Sleep](http://installingcats.com/tag/safe-sleep/), [PleaseSleep](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/29778/pleasesleep), [custom Lingon scripts](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-1994), and probably more besides that.